Separate View and Logic for Android Auto Apps
Hi recently a read that is not necessay create a viewModel for AndroidAuto screens
"Screens are lifecycleOwner but not ViewModelStoreOwner which means that they do not provide a way to manage the ViewModel states out of the box.
You should be calling the repository directly from the Screen class.
Also, the Screen class is responsible for updating the state of the Template, making it act as a ViewModel itself."
But, is that right? and if it's... do exist a way or recommended architecture to separate view and logic for car apps?
